# How to match product codes with subcodes

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, sql-like

Price list of main products vordlusajuhinnak contains 3 prices for product (column toode) and has 39433 products:

```
create table vordlusajuhinnak( toode varchar(60), 
   n2 numeric(8,2), 
   n3 numeric(8,2), 
   n4 numeric(8,2) )
```

toode column in unique, may be primary key in table and contains upper case letters, digits and - characters.

product table (toode) contains 733021 products:

```
CREATE TABLE toode (
    grupp character(1),
    toode character(60) primary key,
    ... lot of other columns
  );
```

Both tables have pattern indexes to speed up queries:

```
CREATE INDEX toode_toode_pattern_idx
    ON toode (toode bpchar_pattern_ops ASC NULLS LAST);
-- This index is probably not used, should removed:    
CREATE INDEX vordlusajuhinnak_toode_pattern_idx ON vordlusajuhinnak(toode bpchar_pattern_ops);
```

Product table as both main products and subproducts with sizes. Size is separated by main product code always by / character:

```
SHOE1
SHOE1-BLACK
SHOE1-BLACK/38
SHOE1-BLACK/41
SHOE1-BLACK/42
SHOE1-BLACK/43
SHOE2
SHOE2/XXL
SHOE2/L
SOMEOTHERWITHOUTSIZE
```

Product codes contain upper case characters only in this table also.

Trying to get prices for all products using

```
create table peatoode as
select toode.toode , n2, n3, n4
from toode, vordlusajuhinnak 
where  toode.toode between vordlusajuhinnak.toode and vordlusajuhinnak.toode||'/z'
```

Takes 4.65 hours. How to speed this query up?
Output from explain:

```
> "Nested Loop  (cost=0.55..272273178.12 rows=3202240012 width=78)" " 
> ->  Seq Scan on vordlusajuhinnak  (cost=0.00..721.33 rows=39433 width=32)" "  ->  Index Only Scan using toode_pkey on toode 
> (cost=0.55..6092.62 rows=81207 width=60)" "        Index Cond: (toode
> >= (vordlusajuhinnak.toode)::bpchar)" "        Filter: ((toode)::text <= ((vordlusajuhinnak.toode)::text || '/z'::text))"
```

Using

> PostgreSQL 13.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1900, 64-bit

in Windows server and psqlODBC driver.

Tried also using like:

```
WHERE toode.toode=vordlusajuhinnak.toode OR 
  toode.toode LIKE vordlusajuhinnak.toode||'/%'
```

Comment: Hi! How do both tables join? The table `peatoode` supposed to be a combination of result sets from `toode` and `vordlusajuhinnak`?

Comment: Join condition is specified in where clause in query in question: result table should contain main product and subproducts (according to query, main product and its subproducts prices are same). Main product is specified in vordlushinnak table. It and and its subproducts should added from product table if main product exists in product table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your data model. You are violating database normalization rules. It is even the very first normalization rule (1NF) you are violating: data in columns must be atomic. You are storing product variants in a table and detect from a substring which variants belong to the same product.

| PRODUCT_VARIANT |
| --- |
| SHOE1 |
| SHOE1-BLACK |
| SHOE1-BLACK/38 |
| SHOE1-BLACK/41 |
| ... |

Instead you want something like:

| PRODUCT | VARIANT |
| --- | --- |
| SHOE1 |  |
| SHOE1-BLACK | 38 |
| SHOE1-BLACK | 41 |
| ... |  |

So there is a one-variant product called SHOE1 and another product called SHOE1-BLACK that has more than one variant.

See that I removed the row for SHOE1-BLACK, as this is a product and not a product variant. Which brings us to the second database normalization rule (2NF). Where would you store the product category (shoes, shirts, etc.)? Here?:

| PRODUCT | VARIANT | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SHOE1 |  | shoes |
| SHOE1-BLACK | 38 | shoes |
| SHOE1-BLACK | 41 | shirts |
| ... |  |  |

Well, this can't be it. SHOE1-BLACK cannot be a pair of shoes and a shirt at the same time. It is very likely hence you need two separate tables, one for the products and one for the product variants:

products:

| PRODUCT_ID | PRODUCT | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SHOE1 | shoes |
| 2 | SHOE1-BLACK | shoes |
| ... |  |  |

variants:

| VARIANT_ID | PRODUCT_ID | VARIANT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 38 |
| 3 | 2 | 41 |
| ... |  |  |

(Well, actually you'd have a category table and maybe many other tables, too.)

Once your database is normalized, querying the data in reasonable time shouldn't be a problem anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change primary key of toode table. It should remain  __toode char(60)__ How to speed up query without changing primary key? Should index on variant number using __split_part( toode, '/',2)__ added and query modified to use it?

Comment: If you must work wth a broken database, then it is only natural that there are issues when writing queries. The least thing you should do in my opinion is to create an additional column for the product only and index that. If you cannot even change the table, then yes, a functional index would help then.